# Сервер отдает файл из кеша

Tags: apache, nginx

День добрый. Подскажите плиз., куда копать. На сервере связка apache + nginx. В конфиге nginx прописано

```
location ~* ^(?!/mysql/).+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|bmp|swf|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|ico|html|htm|txt|woff|ttf|woff2)$ {
    expires 365d;
    try_files $uri @apache2;
} 
location @apache2 {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    include proxy_params;
}
```

Если правильно понимаю, вся статика, если не найден файл, должна перекидываться apache?
Apache загружается с модулями:

```
core_module (static) 
log_config_module (static) 
logio_module (static) 
version_module (static) 
mpm_worker_module (static) 
http_module (static) 
so_module (static)
actions_module (shared) 
alias_module (shared) 
auth_basic_module (shared) 
authn_file_module (shared) 
authz_default_module (shared) 
authz_groupfile_module (shared) 
authz_host_module (shared) 
authz_user_module (shared) 
autoindex_module (shared) 
cgid_module (shared) 
deflate_module (shared) 
dir_module (shared) 
env_module (shared) 
expires_module (shared) 
fcgid_module (shared) 
headers_module (shared) 
include_module (shared) 
mime_module (shared) 
negotiation_module (shared) 
rewrite_module (shared) 
rpaf_module (shared) 
setenvif_module (shared) 
status_module (shared)
```

Проблема в том, что в одной директории кэшируется js (даже при удалении директории отдается файл), хотя вроде как ни в конфиге nginx ни в конфиге apache (в общем то и модулей кэширования то нет) про серверный кэш записей нет. 
Где искать ? Что то идеи закончились.

Comment: Как вы проверяете, что именно сервер отдает, а не браузер из своего кэша берёт без обращения к серверу?

Comment: Заголовки приходят - 200 Ок, последняя модификация 6 месяцев назад. Ну и естественно ctrl + F5, в режиме икогнито, в другом браузере, очистить кэш - все испробовано )